# Saving form POST data across form handler and header call

Tags: php, html, post

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and seeking some help.  Thanks in advanced.  I have a form on a page (guest/build.php) with a bunch of radio buttons:

```
<form action="../php/build.php" method="POST">
<table class="table">
    <caption>Your Computer Parts</caption>
    <tr><th>General Component</th><th>Specific Component</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
    <?php include('buildFunction.php');?>   
</table>
<input id="buyMe" type="submit" value="BUY ME NOW!!!"> 
</form>
```

This sends the data from the radio buttons to my form handler(php/build.php) which makes sure everything has been selected:

```
<?php
include('manageUser.php');
$mainCheck = isset($_POST["chasis"]) && isset($_POST["cpu"]) && isset($_POST["mobo"]) && isset($_POST["ram"]) && isset($_POST["gpu"]) && isset($_POST["psu"]) && isset($_POST["hdd"]) && isset($_POST["monitor"]) && isset($_POST["keyboard"]) && isset($_POST["mouse"]);
if(!$mainCheck){
    redirect("../guest/build.php","Please select 1 of each
    component");
} else {
    redirect("../user/purchase.php","Items Successfully Added");
}
?>
```

And my redirect function (php/manageUser.php):

```
function redirect($url, $message){
session_start();
$_SESSION["message"] = $message;
    //var_dump($_POST);
    //exit;
header("Location: $url");
die;
```

OK, so the results of that commented var_dump are exactly what I want:

```
array(10) { ["chasis"]=> string(1) "3" ["cpu"]=> string(1) "9" ["mobo"]=> string(2) "13" ["ram"]=> string(2) "18" ["gpu"]=> string(2) "22" ["psu"]=> string(2) "27" ["hdd"]=> string(2) "31" ["monitor"]=> string(2) "38" ["keyboard"]=> string(2) "42" ["mouse"]=> string(2) "47" } 
 }
```

However, as soon as I call the header function, I loose the data in the POST array.   I tried saving it into a global variable, but it always registered NULL, and didn't seem proper anyway.

My goal is that the ID's of each item stay in the POST array after the redirect, which I can then use to fill out a price table on the next page(user/purchase.php).

Am I going about this the wrong way?  And if so what is the proper way? I'm trying to stick with PHP at this phase and not use javascript here.

Comment: You will loose the post data because you are navigating to a different page. can you not store them in a DB?

Comment: Well, I need to use the ID's to pull information out of my database on the next page.  It seems like an excessive use of the database, but if that the proper methodology than I suppose I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could come up with two solutions if you don't want to modify the flow of your code:

1. Store the values of all selections in session
2. Append your build.php like build.php?chasis=bla&cpu=blabla, i.e., store the previous selections in $_GET. You could decide how you want to do it in case the uri gets too long, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I think this will work for what I'm needing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SESSION variable to keep the data until the session ends ( it may happen when the client closes the browser).

If you want the data to be persistent you should use a database.

There is one more option, local storage (you can store about 5 MB) but this is a HTML5 standard so older browsers will not support it. For this you don't have to submit any form but you'd have to use javascript to travel from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

Take session_start() out of the function and place it at the beginning of each page that you are using $_SESSION on.

Comment: I had to place this here to solve another problem I was having.  I already have session_start() at the top of every page, but for some reason it wouldn't store the message properly without it here as well.

Comment: Did you try using " global $_SESSION " inside the function instead?